# Self-referencing table vs Mutiple table approach

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a quiz database and I have to incorporate categories into the questions.  I (think) that I have a hierarchical structure that lends itself to a self-referencing table (I have only just come across this concept in my reading).

There are two top levels:
A-level + GCSE-level
Each of these can contain multiple sub-levels (Electricty, Waves, Forces, etc).
Each of these can then contain even more sublevels (Circuits, Resistance, Voltage, etc).

I have thought of two approaches:

1. Level table (id, name) containing two entries (a level + gcse)
2. Subject Table (id, name, level-id (FK)) containing (Electricty, Waves, Forces, etc)
3. There is a join table Subject_Level (id, subject_id, level_id)
4. Topic table (id, topicname, subject-id (FK))

Or one self-referencing table
id, name, parent-id

e.g.

```
1, a-level, null
2, gcse, null
3, electricity, 1
4, electricity, 2
5, circuits, 3
6, circuits, 4
7, current, 3
8, current, 4
etc
```

Which is the best approach for this particular problem?  What if I wanted to put in a higher parent level later on (chem, phys, etc each of which could be a-level, gcse, etc)?

Thank you in advance for reading (hopefully my question is clear),

Martyn

Comment: As I understand the (sub)categories tree is static (insert only). Maybe materialized path is more safe for your task?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.  I will look that up - that is a new one for me.

Comment: I forgot to say, that I need to integrate this into an existing MySQL db where the categories are used in the questions.

Comment: Additional trigger-updated field.

Comment: It is usually bad design to have multiple 'identical' tables.  Go with the self-referencing approach.  Read about "SELF JOIN" and "Hierarchical".